# How to create an Array List with Listbox2 Texts items which are added by listbox1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arraylist

My Global Variable Class:

```
Public Class GlobalVariable
Public Shared containsListBox2Item As ArrayList
End class
```

My Listbox2 Items are: What i am doing is adding listbox 2 items from listbox 1 using a > button which i need all items from listbox2 into an array list and then call it to do another thing. so i want to call each item. not sure how to do so.

```
1. X,Y Coordinate
 2. Latitude, Longitude
 3. Zip Code
 4. State
 5. City
```

Basically i want each listbox.text item to have its own value in the array list. so lets say like

```
If listbox1.text = "X,Y Coordinate" Then
GlobalVariable.containsListBox2Item.add("X,Y Coordinate").
```

Not sure if i coded that properly. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the items not in the ListBox controls, but in Lists. In general, you want to keep your data somewhere not on the UI thread but just use the UI as a display. Ultimately, you will put the items from a List into the ArrayList

Make a winforms project, add a two ListBox and two Button controls.

```
Private list1 As New List(Of String)
Private list2 As New List(Of String)

Private arrayList As New ArrayList()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.Text = ">"
    Button2.Text = "Finish"
    list1.AddRange({"X, Y", "Lat", "Zip", "State", "City"})
    updateListBoxes()
End Sub

Private Sub updateListBoxes()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(list1.ToArray())
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(list2.ToArray())
End Sub

' > button
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim item = ListBox1.Text
    If item = "" Then Exit Sub
    list1.Remove(item)
    list2.Add(item)
    updateListBoxes()
End Sub

' finish button
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    arrayList.Clear()
    arrayList.AddRange(list2.ToArray())
End Sub
```

Comment: please give this question an upvote it has blocked my asking privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to add all item values from ListBox2 to your arraylist.

```
For Each item As ListItem In ListBox2.Items
    GlobalVariable.containsListBox2Item.Add(item.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: still not adding any items into an array list. is there a way to manually add each text item from the list box as a text if it belongs in the listbox?

Comment: does your ListBox2 have any items?

Comment: no items exist but only when i add the item from listbox 1

Comment: If there are no items then how do you expect the items to end up in your arraylist from listbox2?

Comment: whenever i add the items i want it to take a count and add each text item to an array list from the listbox'

Comment: please give this question an upvote it has blocked my asking privileges. it wasn't really a dumb question. not sure who did that :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 'This for adding listbox 2 items from listbox 1
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            ListView2.Items.Add(item.Text)
        Next
        'this for copingall items from listbox2 into an array list
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
            GlobalVariable.containsListBox2Item.Add(item.Text)
        Next
```

Comment: i gave this answer an upvote becuase it helped with adding the items. can you provide an upvote for this question it has blocked my asking privileges. Thanks

Comment: yeah that one solved my issue 100 percent this one helped me add items to the listview!. thank you so much